# SSRS Reporting Parameter Refresh

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I have a SSRS report with a dropdown list that gets dates from an sql query once the user selects the month/year for the report there are two more drop down lists one gets set to the first day of the month and the other gets set to the last day of the month by default these work great. The problem is when the user wants to change the report after they hit view report the two lists that get 1st day and last day do not change. I have already read that this is a problem, but I'm new to ssrs reporting and I was looking for a little help on this.

Comment: Hello Paul, can you please provide screenshots of your "Default Values" and "Available Values" pages for the parameters that are not updating? Thanks.

Comment: I got it worked out thank you for your reply

Comment: @PaulBulling Please post your solution, for the benefit of others with a similar question.  (Or, delete the unanswered question, so it will stop wasting our time.)

Comment: @Paul Bulling I agree, please post your solution or delete the question.  Others were willing to help you with the question... you should contribute to the community you rely on for answers when you need them.